# Pre-populate data tables and charts using shiny_prerendered in Rmd flexdashboard

Tags: shiny, r-markdown, prerender, flexdashboard

I have a shiny app created with Rmd / Flexdashboard with many charts and tables. It is working well. Recently, I started using shiny_prerendered to improve the UX during startup. Now the page loads up faster but all the sections are empty (this is expected - the html renders but the charts and tables are still waiting for data) until the server code runs.

Is it possible to have some placeholder data during setup that will load the shiny output? Reactive outputs are not recognized in the setup context. Is this what the server-start context is for? I have tried too that without success?

Here is a simple code with a two value boxes

````
---
title: "ValueBoxTest"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  vertical_layout: fill
  theme: united
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, options(scipen = 1, digits = 2))
### load packages

```

# ValueBox Test 
===============================================

## Row 1

### Box 1

```{r, context="server"}
output$value1 <-    renderValueBox({
###    p <- 100 starting value placeholder
### call function to generate "p"   
   p <- functionToGenerateValue()
   valueBox(p, icon = "fa-usd")
})
```

```{r echo = FALSE}
valueBoxOutput("value1")
```

## Row 2

### Box 2

```{r, context="server"}
output$value2 <-    renderValueBox({
   ###    q <- 0 starting value placeholder
   ### call function to generate "q"   
   q <- functionToGenerateValue()
    valueBox(q, icon = "fa-usd")
})
```

```{r echo = FALSE}
valueBoxOutput("value2")
````

Answer (score 1):

Well, it may be simpler than you might think. For example, why don't you try to change from runtime:shiny to runtime:shiny_prerendered? It may do the trick.